# UITableviewcontroller reload data issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, xcode5, reloaddata

forgive my ignorance in iPhone programming since I'm a newbie at it.
I'm making an application where there init view controller is UITable view controller for displaying data and another View controller for entering data.

my problem is when I enter a new data it won't appear in the UItable controller and I tried to reload the data using `[self.tableview reloadData]` in `viewDidLoad` but the data won't reload and since I'm using a custom delegate I tried writing `[self.tableview reloadData]` as last line of my custom delegate but it didn't work either and I tried using `viewDidAppear` but that didn't work also.

here is the code:

MainViewController.m (TableView)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Initializing conference array");

    conferenceData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    SavingData *loadData = [[SavingData alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"Loading the file then fill it in an array");
    conferenceData = [loadData LoadDataArray];

    NSLog(@"Done Initializing conference array");

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [conferenceData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    NSLog(@"writing data in cell number %i",indexPath.row);
    cell.textLabel.text = [[conferenceData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];

    return cell;
}

// Implementing the adding delegate
-(void) setInformation:(Adding *)controller withObject:(Conference *)info
{
    Conference *confer = info; //Temprory Conference object to store data
    SavingData *saveToFile = [[SavingData alloc]init];

    if ([saveToFile SavingDataWithObject:confer]) //Calling SavingDataWithObject method and check if the save operation return true or false
    {
        NSLog(@"Done Saving !!");
    }
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // after saving return to the main window
    NSLog(@"Should be popped right now");
}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];`

cell can be nil here, so you might not actually be returing a cell.

Try using

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

This function will never return nil.

But first you must register what `@Cell` is.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    ...
 }
```

Alternatively you could check if cell is nil, and create it if it isn't, but I think this approach is cleaner.

One last thought, double check that when you call `reloadData` your array is actually populated, you can set a break point in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to make sure it's called the appropriate number of times.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

Apparently when I wrote the codes in `-viewWillAppear` method it works fine the table reload the data.

Thank you very much for helping me